# ContextualHelp on Infragistics XamFormulaEditor and FormulaEditorDialog

Tags: .net, wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid, formula-editor

I am trying to integrate the formula editing feature with my XamDataGrid control in our WPF application. The control has its AutoGenerateFields property set to false and it binds data successfully. I have a XamFormulaEditor control on the Window to allow the user build his own formula and add the result as a new field(column) into the existing XamDataGrid.

I have set the Target property of the XamFormulaEditor as

Target="{Binding ElementName=xamGrid}".

I can enter the formula like "[Last4] + 2" and have my new column with correct value. The problem is that when I use the built in ContextualHelp feature by using the autocomplete suggestions and the operands list, the result goes wrong as the source column is always of Row at 0, because the formula becomes like

[//dataPresenterAdapter/Table(0)/counsel_Status_Id]

Basically we need to have a FormulaEditor control that can be used to create a new Field in the XamDataGrid using CalculationManager.

Do any of you have an idea that might be useful in this context?

Or do you have a sample that implements the same logic?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code fro the grid and formula editor?

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking into your issue, but if you could attach an isolated sample project, where the issue is reproduced, it will be easier to determne where the issue comes from.